# Android CountDownTimer, Circular Seekbar not updating every tick

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, android-seekbar

I'm trying to make an application that smoothly renders this seekbar. I found I needed a precise animation, setting the seekbar to 500 steps. I'm using the circular seekbar found [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar). As you can see below, my calculated value on tick is normal, yet my seekbar only updates approx every 1 second.

Below you'll see that my calculated value in my output log does not correspond to the seekbar progress value.

My seekbar is initialized in the follwing way.

```
circularSeekbar = new CircularSeekBar(this);
        circularSeekbar = (CircularSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.circularSeekBar);
        circularSeekbar.setMaxProgress(500);
        circularSeekbar.setProgress(50);
        circularSeekbar.invalidate();
        circularSeekbar.setBackGroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        circularSeekbar.setRingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

And my countdowntimer ontick

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                float progress = (float) millisUntilFinished / ms;
                progress = 1 - progress;
                progress *= 500;

                circularSeekbar.setProgress((int) (progress));
                circularSeekbar.invalidate();

                Log.d("Progress: ", Float.toString(progress));
                Log.d("Bar Progress: ", Integer.toString(circularSeekbar.getProgress()));
```

and my log, you can see my actual progress calculated vs the current value, obviously not being updated per tick.

[image]

Comment: Problem are in library you use. CircularSeekBar take integer than translate this value to angle for draw circular than update progress use round of angle value. so many round. Use other library or try fix this lib

Comment: @adrbtk thanks, I was able to change all the corresponding ints in CircularSeekBar to floating point and it works as I would like it to.